# Android: changing tab must refresh my listview of the db

Tags: android, database, tabs, refresh

i have an application made with tab host.
i need to refresh my listview (the second tab) when clicked.
this view contain the db data, it's obvious that it need to be always up to date (because in the entire app i make update,insert,delete,...
how can i?

this is the onCreate in the class called by the tab

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks); 
    final Database info=new Database(this); 
    final Timer t = new Timer(); 
    info.open(); 
    final Cursor data=info.getData(); 
    final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_mia); 
    String[] from = new String[] {"contenuto"};
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data, from, to); 
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is the tab class (the "incriminated class is bookmarks)

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    // Tab per lettore
    TabSpec lettoretab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Lettore");
    lettoretab.setIndicator("Lettore", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lettore));
    Intent lettoreIntent = new Intent(this, Lettore.class);
    lettoretab.setContent(lettoreIntent);
    // Tab per bookmarks
    TabSpec bookmarkstab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Bookmarks");
    bookmarkstab.setIndicator("Bookmarks", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmarks));
    Intent bookmarksIntent = new Intent(this, Bookmarks.class);
    bookmarkstab.setContent(bookmarksIntent);
    // Tab per create
    TabSpec createtabs = tabHost.newTabSpec("Create");
    createtabs.setIndicator("Create", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.create));
    Intent createIntent = new Intent(this, Create.class);
    createtabs.setContent(createIntent);
    // Tab per feed
    TabSpec feedtabs = tabHost.newTabSpec("Feed");
    feedtabs.setIndicator("Feed", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.feed));
    Intent feedIntent = new Intent(this, Feeds.class);
    feedtabs.setContent(feedIntent);
    // Tab per actionmobileapp
    TabSpec actionmobileapptabs = tabHost.newTabSpec("App");
    actionmobileapptabs.setIndicator("App", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionmobileapp));
    Intent actionmobileappIntent = new Intent(this, Actionmobileapp.class);
    actionmobileapptabs.setContent(actionmobileappIntent);
    // Aggiungo i tabs
    tabHost.addTab(lettoretab);
    tabHost.addTab(bookmarkstab);
    tabHost.addTab(createtabs);
    tabHost.addTab(feedtabs);
    tabHost.addTab(actionmobileapptabs);
```

i've tried recalling the code in onResume but no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);
            View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                    R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
            TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(labelId);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

            spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
            spec.setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

add this in TabActivity class inside the addTab().

Thanks....

Comment: sorry but i don't understand exactly what you mean: i've edited my question with the tab class

Comment: Please add intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) in your addTab() in TabActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a duplicate of this:

[SimpleCursorAdapter not Updating with DB Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985955/android-simplecursoradapter-not-updating-with-database-changes)

You should check the Android documentation for LoaderManager which is what you want to use.

[LoaderManager Class Reference with Code Example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)

Comment: not true. requery or other things is not my question. i can't recall the cursor or requery in this way. also, the view don't change.

Answer (score 0):

make 'adpater' variable public in 'Activity' and in `onResume` call this mett`adapter.swapCursor(c)` here `c` is your new-updated cursor. don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after it.