# When is the onLoaderReset callback supposed to run?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I am noticing that when I `restartLoader`, the `onLoaderReset` callback does not run.  I also tried doing a manual `reset` on the `Loader` itself, but that didn't work either.

I did find [this bug ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68896), but I thought that surely it would have more attention.

I would like to mention that I am fairly certain that I have the Loaders configured properly.  Everything else is working perfectly, including `the other two callbacks`.

**Note:** If anyone is curious, I am using a CursorLoader to refresh a CursorAdapter backing a ListView.  I am setting the Cursor on the CursorAdapter to null in onLoaderReset, but because it doesn't get called there is a small window where the ListView's contents are stale.

Comment: CursorAdapter refreshes automatically if the content of the Uri it refers to changes

Comment: @pskink I have been using `swapCursor` to refresh, with a `Loader` to get the new `Cursor`.  Is that not how I should be doing it?

Comment: are you using your custom ContentProvider?

Comment: @pskink `CommonsWare` suggests obtaining a `fresh Cursor` and calling `swapCursor` [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986071/1747491).  That is what I am doing, so I implemented a `Loader` to obtain the `fresh Cursor`.